# Anaconda 環境で pyinstaller を利用した際の MKL のライセンス

Tags: python, ライセンス

表題の通り Anaconda 環境で pyinstaller を利用し実行ファイルを生成を行います。
実行ファイルを作るシステムに Numpy を含んでいるため MKL が含まれます。

この実行ファイルを有償配布を考えており、MKL の再配布に当たると考えられるのですが、intel との契約なしに配布しても大丈夫なのでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

有償化するソフトに関しては確認しておいた方が良いかもしれません。
まずは弁護士とか、自分の会社の法務部などに問い合わせることでしょうね。

基本的にはランセンスの条項に従っていれば配布しても大丈夫なようです。

[Home › Forums › Intel® Software Development Products › Intel® Math Kernel Library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/802160)
質問

> Hello MKL fans and sorry for such stupid question >.<
>
> We are some open Source developer who working at the moment on a project called "NumSharp" which shall offers the same APIs from numpy but for .NET languages.
>
> When implementing LAPACK functionalities we saw that there are multiple lapack providers (or LAPACK libs) like NetLib standard LAPACK, MKL, ....and so want to give users the possibility to choose free which licensed provider they want to use.
>
> Sure MKL is one of the most popular. Since anaconda distro using the MKL lib in so many packages like numpy - we was thinking about offering MKL and  different other LAPACK providers (native libs) as .NET package / nuget package.
>
> Licensing is always a sensitive topic and so we were discussing in https://github.com/SciSharp/NumSharp/issues/116.
>
> Now our question
>
> is it allowed to distribute the MKL dlls in package like nuget or is it totally forbitten and everybody has to install by him or herself?
>
> Sorry for this question but we do not want to do sth wrong and so better ask then do.
>
> Wish all a nice day and thanks for your time.

回答

> Hi ,
>
> please refer here : [license FAQ](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl/license-faq)
>
> you won't have a problem redistributing it.
>
> Thank you

---

FAQの抜粋
[Intel® Math Kernel Library License FAQ](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl/license-faq)

> This information is for general guidance. For the licensing terms for Intel® Math Kernel Library (Intel® MKL), consult the Intel Simplified Software License (ISSL).
>
> [Intel Simplified Software License](https://software.intel.com/en-us/license/intel-simplified-software-license)
>
> **Can I redistribute Intel MKL?**
>   Yes, redistribution is allowed per the terms of the ISSL.
>
> **Do I need to pay royalty fees when I redistribute this library?**
>   No, there are no royalty fees.
>
> **Are there limits to the number of copies of my application that I can distribute with this resource?**
>   No, there are no redistribution limits.
>
> **Is including this library in a publicly-available container such as Docker* allowed?**
>   Yes, you can include Intel MKL in a public container.
>
> **Can I install and use this resource on cloud servers from providers such as Amazon Web Services (AWS)*?**
>   Yes, you are allowed to perform these actions on any cloud server.
>
> **To benefit multiple users, can I install and make this library available on a cluster?**
>   Yes, you can install Intel MKL on a cluster and provide it to users.
>
> インテルMKLを再配布できますか？
>   はい、ISSLの条項に従って再配布が許可されています。
>
> このライブラリを再配布する際にロイヤリティ料を支払う必要がありますか？
>   いいえ、ロイヤリティ料はかかりません。
>
> このリソースで配布できるアプリケーションのコピーの数に制限はありますか？
>   いいえ、再配布の制限はありません。
>
> このライブラリをDocker *などの公開されているコンテナーに含めることは許可されていますか？
>   はい、インテルMKLをパブリックコンテナーに含めることができます。
>
> Amazon Web Services（AWS）*などのプロバイダーからクラウドサーバーにこのリソースをインストールして使用できますか？
>   はい、クラウドサーバーでこれらのアクションを実行できます。
>
> 複数のユーザーに利益をもたらすために、クラスターにこのライブラリをインストールして利用可能にできますか？
>   はい。インテルMKLをクラスターにインストールして、ユーザーに提供できます。

---

ライセンスの抜粋
[Intel Simplified Software License (Version April 2018)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/license/intel-simplified-software-license)

> Copyright (c) 2018 Intel Corporation.
>
> Use and Redistribution.  You may use and redistribute the software (the “Software”), without modification, provided the following conditions are met:
>
> * Redistributions must reproduce the above copyright notice and the following terms of use in the Software and in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
>
> * Neither the name of Intel nor the names of its suppliers may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this Software without specific prior written permission.
>
> * No reverse engineering, decompilation, or disassembly of this Software is permitted.
>
> 使用と再配布。次の条件が満たされている場合、お客様は修正なしでソフトウェア（「ソフトウェア」）を使用および再配布できます。
>
> *再配布では、上記の著作権表示および以下のソフトウェアの使用条件、および配布で提供されるドキュメントおよび/またはその他の資料を複製する必要があります。
>
> *事前の書面による特別な許可なしに、Intelの名前もサプライヤーの名前も、このソフトウェアから派生した製品を推奨または宣伝するために使用することはできません。
>
> *このソフトウェアのリバースエンジニアリング、逆コンパイル、または分解は許可されていません。

以下省略